# как реализовать placeholder для select

Tags: html, валидация, html-select, placeholder, required

Проблема в следующем если использовать `<option disabled select>что то</option>`, то по умолчанию выбирается "что-то", и нельзя использовать `required` для `select`, так как уже выбрано "что-то". В связи с этим вопрос как реализовать `placeholder` для `select`. Отдельным блоком с `position: absolute`, не использую, может есть что-то получше.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте чтото типа

```
<select id="first"><option value="0">Choose it</option><option value="1">1</option></select>
```

А дальше через Jquery делайте проверку типа

```
if($('#first').val()=='0'){alert('Choose it');}
```